# Move jsfiddle to site

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jsfiddle

I have a code working in JSFiddle

```
$('#choice_17_9_1').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('#choice_17_9_2').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#label_17_9_2').css('color', '#cccccc');


  } else {
    $('#choice_17_9_2').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#label_17_9_2').css('color', '#000000');



  }
});

$('#choice_17_9_2').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('#choice_17_9_1').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#label_17_9_1').css('color', '#cccccc');

  } else {
    $('#choice_17_9_1').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#label_17_9_1').css('color', '#000000');



  }
});
// second pair
$('#choice_17_9_3').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('#choice_17_9_15').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#label_17_9_15').css('color', '#cccccc');


  } else {
    $('#choice_17_9_15').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#label_17_9_15').css('color', '#000000');



  }
});

$('#choice_17_9_15').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('#choice_17_9_3').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#label_17_9_3').css('color', '#cccccc');

  } else {
    $('#choice_17_9_3').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#label_17_9_3').css('color', '#000000');



  }
});

// third pair
$('#choice_17_9_5').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('#choice_17_9_7').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#label_17_9_7').css('color', '#cccccc');


  } else {
    $('#choice_17_9_7').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#label_17_9_7').css('color', '#000000');



  }
});

$('#choice_17_9_7').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('#choice_17_9_5').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#label_17_9_5').css('color', '#cccccc');

  } else {
    $('#choice_17_9_5').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#label_17_9_5').css('color', '#000000');



  }
});
```

I've tried to move it to my WordPress site but it isn't functioning.

The above code is in a file that is loaded via functions.php file.

I also load Jquery 3.2.1 via the functions.php file using code shown here: https://wpengine.com/support/including-a-different-jquery-version-in-wordpress/

I don't know if I need to add anything to the js file beyond what is in the JS pane of jsfiddle or add an onload function to the HTML...is there something i'm missing?

I've tried wrapping the code in a window.onload function. And also tried adding the js code to the header.php instead of loading an external file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there any errors being displayed in your browser console?

Comment: Yes. When I inspect element and view the console there is an error related to the JS. However, the JS is exactly as it is in the fiddle.  See screen shot: http://nimb.ws/zShtjx

Comment: Are you sure you are loading jQuery before your code?

Comment: The wpengine article you link to notes that you need to add jQuery as a dependency for any javascript files you add, have you done that? The error message in your browser console means that jQuery hasn't been loaded before your javascript is being run.

Comment: Yes. It loads jquery 3.2.1 via the functions file per the wpengine article, then loads the jquery from WordPress in wp-includes and then finally loads my js from the fiddle (mutuallyexclusiveform.js). See http://nimb.ws/bURo93.

I've also tried eliminating the loading of jquery 3.2.1 to use just the WP version (which appears to be jQuery v1.12.4). I believe this version also works in jsfiddle.

Comment: You are aliasing jQuery as `jQuery3_2_1` Have you tried using `jQuery3_2_1('#choice_17_9_1').change(function() {...` instead?

Comment: is that instead of the $ in
    $('#choice_17_9_1').change(function() {

Comment: That's how it works. Take a look at this: [link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: If i remove jquery 3.2.1 and instead just rely on the core library supplied with wordpress, do I still need to change the dollar sign?

Comment: I just adjusted the JSFiddle and replaced the $ throughout the js to use jquery. It does work on the fiddle but still doesn't work on the site.  I have remove the function to included jquery 3.2.1 so the site just uses the core wordpress jquery and have changed my script back to use $.  I'm still at a loss.

Comment: You can forget about the fiddle now, that's only a prototype. Look at the last example in the link I sent you. See how they use the alias `jq162 = jQuery.noConflict( true );` for the second version of jQuery it uses. In theory, if you are going to use a single version of jQ, then you don't need an alias

Comment: I've switched to the single version of JQuery. But for some reason, this still doesn't run on the site. thanks for trying to instruct me.

Comment: I managed to make this work. Thanks to all who looked into it.